# finitness of syntomic/fppf cohomology with coefficients in a finite flat group scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, cohomology, positive-characteristic

Let $X/k$ be a smooth projective variety over a finite field of characteristic $p$ and $\mathscr{A}/X$ be an Abelian scheme.

Is then $H^1_\mathrm{SYN}(X,\mathscr{A}[p]) = H^1_\mathrm{fppf}(X,\mathscr{A}[p])$ finite?

This is true if $X$ is a curve, see [Milne, Arithmetic Duality Theorems http://jmilne.org/math/Books/ADTnot.pdf ], p. 292, Lemma III.8.9.

Edit: I know it in the case $\mathscr{A} = A \times_k X$ is a *constant* Abelian scheme since then $H^1(X,\mathscr{A})[p]$ is finite and the Kummer sequence induces a short exact sequence $$0 \to \mathscr{A}(X)/p \to H^1_\mathrm{SYN}(X,\mathscr{A}[p]) \to H^1(X,\mathscr{A})[p] \to 0$$ and $\mathscr{A}(X)/p$ is finite by the Mordell-Weil theorem.

Comment: From a quick inspection it seems that Theorem III.5.6 implies the case where $\mathcal A[p]$ or its dual has height one. The only place where the proof of Lemma 8.9 uses that $X$ is a curve is to make a filtration by height one pieces (using Lemma B.1). Is this known to fail for higher-dimensional varieties?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I don't think any nontrivial  filtration can exist of $\mathcal A[p]$ for $A$ the moduli space of abelian varieties - over the ordinary locus, only the canonical subgroup is preserved by monodromy, but that doesn't extend to the supersingular points. Presumably things aren't much better on compact Shimura subvarieties, say.

Comment: @WillSawin: ah, that makes sense. In fact, going from the ordinary to the supersingular locus makes me appreciate the existence of such a filtration over a curve much more.

Comment: So do you think the statement is wrong for $X$ higher dimensional? Or just that there is no easy generalisation of Milne's argument?

Comment: So far we only discussed the latter. It is very well possible that the result is still true by a different argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$ be a finite field. Let $X$ be a normal proper variety. Let $G$ be a finite flat commutative group scheme over $X$ of order a power of $p$.

Lemma 1. If $T$ is a $G$-torsor over $X$ and $T$ is trivial over the generic point of $X$, then $T$ is trivial.

Proof. Namely, let $X' \subset T$ be the scheme theoretic closure of the rational section we get from the triviality of $T$ over the generic point. Then $X' \to X$ is a birational finite morphism, hence an isomorphism as $X$ is normal. QED

Lemma 2. Let $Z$ be a proper scheme over $X$. Then $G(Z)$ is finite.

Proof. We may pull back $G$ to $Z$. Then we see it suffices to show that given $\pi : Y \to Z$ finite flat, there are only a finite number of
sections $\tau$ of $\pi$. This is clear because a section is given by a
$\mathcal{O}_Z$-algebra map $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_Y \to \mathcal{O}_Z$ and we have finiteness of
$H^0(Z, \mathcal{H}om(\pi_*\mathcal{O}_Y, \mathcal{O}_Z))$
as $Z$ is proper over the finite field $k$.

Lemma 3. Let $Y \to X$ be an alteration of proper varieties with $X$
normal. Then $\ker(H^1(X, G) \to H^1(Y, G))$ is finite.

Proof. If $Y \to X$ is a blow up, then the kernel is trivial by Lemma 1. There exists a blowup $X' \to X$ such that the strict transform $Y'$ of $Y$ is flat over $X'$ (google "flattening by blowing up"). Of course we may assume $X'$ is normalize (if not then just normalize $X'$). Combining these two steps we may assume $Y \to X$ is finite flat.

Assume $Y \to X$ is finite flat. Say $T \to X$ is a $G$-torsor which becomes trivial over $Y$. Choose a section $\sigma : Y \to T \times_X Y$.
Using that $T \times_X (Y \times_X Y)$ is a $G$-torsor over $Y \times_X Y$
we can take the "difference" between $\sigma \circ \text{pr}_0$ and $\sigma \circ \text{pr}_1$ over $Y \times_X Y$ to get an element
$$
\tau = \sigma \circ \text{pr}_0 - \sigma \circ \text{pr}_1 \in
G(Y \times_X Y)
$$
I leave it to the reader to see that $\tau$ determines the
isomorphism class of the torsor $T$ by descent theory for the
fppf covering $\{Y \to X\}$. By Lemma 2 there are only a finite
number of $\tau$. QED

Proposition. $H^1(X, G)$ is finite.

Proof. By Lemma 3 we may replace $X$ by an alteration. Hence we may assume that over the function field of $X$ we have a filtration of $G$ by closed
subgroup schemes such that the successive quotients have order $p$.
(This step requires you to know about finite group schemes over fields;
you can read about this in the book by Mumford about abelian
varieties for example.)
Any closed subgroup scheme of the generic fibre of $G$
extends to a finite flat closed subgroup scheme over
a blowup of $X$ by the same flattening techniques as used
in the proof of Lemma 3.
Thus finally we may assume there is a filtration
$$
(0) \subset G_1 \subset \ldots \subset G_{n - 1} \subset G_n
$$
where $G_i/G_{i - 1}$ is a finite flat group scheme of order $p$.
In this way (using the long exact cohomology sequence) we reduce
to the case where $G$ has order $p$.

Now we use the classification of such group schemes over the normal
variety $X$ (you can easily deduce what I say from the Oort-Tate
paper). There are two cases.

The first case is where $G$ is a
closed subgroup scheme of a line bundle $L$ over $X$. In this case
there is a sequence
$$
0 \to G \to L \to L^{(p)} \to 0
$$
for some additive map as indicated. Since the cohomology of $L$
and $L^{(p)}$ are finite, we win.

The second case is where $G$ is a Galois twist of $\mu_p$ in the
generic point. Here we can (after replacing $X$ by an alteration
again if necessary) assume that $G|_U = \mu_{p, U}$ for some
Zariski op $U$. Then we can use that $H^1(X, G) \subset H^1(U, G)$
by Lemma 1 and use the finiteness of $H^1(U, \mu_p)$. QED

Comment: Thank you very much! I will read this in the next weeks!

Comment: Can you please give more details for: "By Lemma 3 we may replace $X$ by an alteration. Hence we may assume that over the function field of $X$ we have a filtration of $G$ by closed subgroup schemes such that the successive quotients have order $p$." and why the Tate-Oort classification gives exactly the two cases you mention?

Comment: Regarding 1): The category of finite flat commutative group schemes of $p$-power order is Abelian, and over an algebraically closed field, its simple objects are $\mu_p,\alpha_p$ and $\mathbf{Z}/p$. Perhaps this helps; regarding 2): Since $X$ has characteristic $p$, the element $w_p$ of [Tate-Oort] is $= 0$, and if $a=0$, the $p$-Lie algebra of $G$ is $\mathscr{L}$ with the $p$-power morphism.

Comment: If $Y \to X$ is an alteration with $Y$ normal and $H^1(Y, G)$ is finite, then Lemma 3 tells us $H^1(X, G)$ is finite. Hence we may replace $X$ by $Y$.

Comment: This is clear to me. My question was 1) why there exists such a filtration after an alteration, and 2) why the Tate-Oort classification gives us the two cases.

Comment: 1) If you have a closed subscheme of the generic fibre, then the closure is a closed subscheme of $G$ over $X$, but may not be flat. Then after a blowup the strict transform is flat and still a closed subscheme. 2) Just look at the equations for the group schemes in Oort-Tate paper. As you say one gets $\mu_p$, $Z/pZ$, of $\alpha_p$ in the generic point. In the last two cases looking at the invertible sheaf you mention gives a group scheme homomorphism $G \to L$ and then you just show the quotient is another line bundle $L'$ but the map $L \to L'$ is not linear, just additive.